# Select all rows up to and including first occurrence by group in a data frame

Tags: r

I ve been scratching my head a little about how to do. I'm reorganising some unbalanced panel data (stacked/long format). I need to keep all the rows up to and including the first occurrence of variable (indc=D) value by group (id) and also keep the rows for groups where this has not occurred yet. The only rows I wish to discard are rows per group where there is a second or more value of the indicator variable (indc=D). I also need to keep all the columns in the dataframe.

```
# Data 
id<-factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4))
time<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2)
indc<-factor(c("C","C","D","C","C","C","D","D","C","C","C","C","D","D","C","C"))
var1<-sample(seq(1,8.5, by=0.5))
var2<-c(rep(1,8),rep(0,8))

df<-data.frame(id,time,indc,var1,var2)
```

My attempt is using by and match - problem is it returns the last variable as a match and the indices for each group. I m stuck on how to get to the final solution.

```
attempt<-by(df, df$id, function(x) {match(unique(x$indc=="D"), x$indc=="D")} )

results<-(do.call("rbind", attempt))
```

The desired result is df2 `df2<-df[c(1:3,4:7,9:13,15:16),]`

I'd be very grateful if anyone has ideas on a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is to use dplyr to group by "id" and then calculate a cumulative sum of the rows where "indc == "D". Then check and filter all the rows where this cumsum is <= 1.

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(cumsum(indc == "D") <= 1)
#Source: local data frame [14 x 5]
#Groups: id
#
#   id time indc var1 var2
#1   1    1    C  1.5    1
#2   1    2    C  1.0    1
#3   1    3    D  7.0    1
#4   2    1    C  2.5    1
#5   2    2    C  3.5    1
#6   2    3    C  6.5    1
#7   2    4    D  3.0    1
#8   3    1    C  2.0    0
#9   3    2    C  7.5    0
#10  3    3    C  6.0    0
#11  3    4    C  8.0    0
#12  3    5    D  8.5    0
#13  4    1    C  4.0    0
#14  4    2    C  4.5    0
```

---

#### Edit #1 after comments:

Thanks to @akrun's comments below, here are tow more options of how to subset:

Option 1: using base R:

```
df[with(df, ave(indc=='D', id, FUN=function(x) cumsum(x)<=1)),]
```

Option 2: using data.table:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.SD[cumsum(indc=='D')<=1], by=id]
```

Credit goes to @akrun

---

#### Edit #2 after comment by OP:

It was not 100% clear how you want rows removed if, for example, the first "D" has occured and then there is another row in the same group where "C" occurs (or some other letter). My initial answer would keep such a row if it occured after the first "D" occurence. To change that behavior and remove all rows after the first "D" occurence, you can simply add another `cumsum` to the code, like this (for the modified data as presented below):

```
df %>% group_by(id2) %>% filter(cumsum(cumsum(indc2 == "D")) <= 1L)
#Source: local data frame [13 x 5]
#Groups: id2
#
#   id2 time2 indc2 var1 var2
#1    1     1     C  8.0    1
#2    1     2     C  5.0    1
#3    1     3     D  7.0    1
#4    2     1     C  1.0    1
#5    2     2     C  2.0    1
#6    2     3     D  9.0    1
#7    3     1     C  4.5    0
#8    3     2     C  3.0    0
#9    3     3     C  7.5    0
#10   3     4     C  1.5    0
#11   3     5     D  4.0    0
#12   4     1     C  6.0    0
#13   4     2     C  6.5    0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4"), class = "factor"), time2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2), indc2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), var1 = c(8, 5, 7, 8.5, 1, 2, 9, 3.5, 
2.5, 4.5, 3, 7.5, 1.5, 4, 5.5, 6, 6.5), var2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("id2", "time2", 
"indc2", "var1", "var2"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")

> df
   id2 time2 indc2 var1 var2
1    1     1     C  8.0    1
2    1     2     C  5.0    1
3    1     3     D  7.0    1
4    1     4     C  8.5    1    <-- this row will also be removed now
5    2     1     C  1.0    1
6    2     2     C  2.0    1
7    2     3     D  9.0    1
8    2     4     D  3.5    1
9    2     5     D  2.5    0
10   3     1     C  4.5    0
11   3     2     C  3.0    0
12   3     3     C  7.5    0
13   3     4     C  1.5    0
14   3     5     D  4.0    0
15   3     6     D  5.5    0
16   4     1     C  6.0    0
17   4     2     C  6.5    0
```

Comment: Your last two answer were very nice

Comment: Thanks, @RichardScriven. And good point, akrun (+1). There are of course many ways to achieve this (which will probably use the same logic but implement it in different ways).

Comment: @akrun, those are very valid and good options. Why not post them as answers?

Comment: @beginneR These are all using the same logic as yours.  So, I am not posting it.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the responses. I tried both and they seem to work. I did notices a quirk - if we add an 4th row of C for the group id=1, the first group contains an unwanted row. Not major, I can delete. Any idea why this happens?id2<-factor(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4))
indc2<-factor(c("C","C","D","C", "C","C","D","D","D","C","C","C","C","D","D","C","C"))
time2<-c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2)

Comment: @RVNorman, I updated my answer with a little modification. Does it work as expected now?

Comment: Thanks, I should have specified that D should be the final state. All the answers were really useful.

Comment: I think the data.table solution also needs two concatenated cumsums in order to work with situations such as C,C,D,C